# Mysql Join on table twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Im having issues trying to join a table twice.

I have 3 tables: Users, Auctions, Bids

Both Auctions and Bids contain a column called **user_ID** that relates to the Users table **ID**.

The user_ID for each relates to the Seller(Auction Table) and Winner(Bids Table)

How do I join all 3 so that I have a row with:
auction_ID, auction_status, seller_name, seller_email, winner_name, winner_email

Ive tried doing an inner join with no success.

Table structure as follows:

**User Table**
ID,
user_login,
user_email

**Bids Table**
ID,
user_ID,
auct_ID,
created,
amount

**Auctions Table**
ID,
user_ID,
title,
end_time

SO at the moment I have the following query:

SELECT a.ID as auct_ID, a.status, s.user_email as seller, w.user_email as bidder, b.amount, b.created FROM auctions a
INNER JOIN bids b ON b.auct_ID = a.id
INNER JOIN users s ON a.user_ID = s.id 
INNER JOIN users w ON b.user_ID = w.id WHERE status='active' AND a.end_time < NOW() ORDER BY amount

Which gives me all the bids of one auction that has expired. I want all auctions that have expired and only want the top bidder.

Comment: Post what you have tried - SO is not rent-a-coder

Comment: can you please post the CREATE statements for all three tables so that it's easier to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
SELECT a.*, s.*, w.*, b.* FROM auctions a
INNER JOIN bids b ON b.auction_id = a.id
INNER JOIN users s ON a.user_ID = s.id 
INNER JOIN users w ON b.user_ID = w.id 
WHERE .....
ORDER BY b.amount DESC LIMIT 1
```

the `s` and `w` table alias is for `sellers` and `winners`

Comment: Hey Tudor thanks for the help. The query seems to work but how do i limit this to the top bidder?

Comment: You could say SELECT TOP 1 a.*... and then ORDER BY the amount in the `bids` table in a descending order.